# "Zumal" and "besonders"

Tags: word-choice, difference

My questions are:

1. In what contexts are they used?
2. Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Although you got a good answer, you gave us no context for this question, and a quick look at Duden, Wiktionary, dict.cc, or Leo, could've shown the difference between these two words.

Comment: Since *zumal* can be also used as a coordinating conjunction I can see that there is confusion. I don't think this question deserves downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the adverbial use of *zumal*, it's related to *besonders* by, so to say, the following equivalence:

```
zumal = besonders weil
```

Examples:

> Ich würde nie wieder diese Partei wählen, zumal sie letzes Jahr nur Scheiße gebaut hat.
>
> Ich würde nie wieder diese Partei wählen, besonders weil sie letzes Jahr Scheiße gebaut hat.

But it is conjunction as well, meaning *auch weil* (*and besides*, according to Emanuel's comment):

> Er war wegen seiner lockeren Art beim Chef nicht besonders beliebt, zumal er häufig zu spät kam.

as one sees from Wiktionary.

Comment: I'd like to add that "zumal" can also carry the meaning "and besides"... it doesn't always focus as much as "besonders" does. So every "besonders weil" can be a "zumal" but not ice versa

Comment: I don't think the two variants are equivalent. IMO, in the election example, the "zumal" sentence implies to me that your decision not to vote for that party again is set in stone for other reasons already, and the party's actions during the last year just confirm your objections. The "besonders weil" sentence, on the other hand, implies that, despite not having been a fan of the party before,  last year's actions are the crucial factor for your decision.